# Помогите найти ошибку в SQL запросе В VC# 2010

Tags: c#, sql

Помогите у меня постоянно пишет ошибку... если надо я её тоже напишу, вот код который я использую:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            MySqlConnection cnt = new MySqlConnection(strProvider);
            try
            {
                cnt.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE Settings SET seconds = '" + numericUpDown1.Value + "');", cnt);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cnt.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Сайт успешно обновлен");
            }
            catch(MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка");
            }
    }
```

Comment: Разберитесь со скобками, апострофами и кавычками в строчной части команды

Comment: Дак вроде, по примеру делал только таблицу другую поставил и откуда брать значения...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вот ваш запрос:

```
UPDATE Settings SET seconds = '123');
```

- уберите последнюю скобку - она не нужна
- какого типа поле `seconds`? если `int`, то вам прийдётся сделать следующие:
  конвертировать строковое значение `numericUpDown1.Value` в `int`
- определить какое именно поле будет обновлятся - добавить оператор `WHERE`
- **не использовать конкатенацию строк в SQL ВООБЩЕ НИКОГДА!**

вот:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE Settings SET seconds = " + Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value) + ";", cnt);
```

но ещё лучше будет выглядеть следующий код:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Settings SET seconds = @Sec WHERE id = 42", cnt);//допустим id = 42

SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();

//задаем имя параметра
param.ParameterName = "@Sec";

//задаем значение параметра
param.Value = numericUpDown1.Value;
//param.Value = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value); если sеconds int
//param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;

//задаем тип параметра
param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;

//передаем параметр объекту класса SqlCommand
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: УРА! ОНА ЗАРАБОТАЛА!!А для string, что использовать?

Comment: используйте параметризованые запросы, а ещё лучше - хранимые процедуры